# How to make my corners rounded?

Tags: html, css

In this design I set in the CSS to have rounded corners but only the two corners at the top are not. How I can make them also rounded ?

```css
.pricing-page li {
  width: 32%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 22px rgba(157, 184, 209, 0.19);
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pricing-page">
  <li class="animated bounceInLeft delay-250">
    <div style="background-color: #0169b2">
      <div style="text-align: left; width: 10%; padding: 5px 0 0 5px;"><img src="assets/images/image.png"></div>
      <h5>Dedicated Server</h5>
      <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available.</p>
      <span><b>From</b></span>
      <div class="price">80$<span>/month</span></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Add `overflow: hidden` to the `li`. Or add `border-radius` to the child `div`

Comment: If you are using JQuery, simply add "ui-corner-all" to the class attribute of your div-element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0` to parent div

```css
.pricing-page li {
  width: 32%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 22px rgba(157, 184, 209, 0.19);
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pricing-page">
  <li class="animated bounceInLeft delay-250">
    <div style="background-color: #0169b2; border-radius: 
10px 10px 0 0;">
      <div style="text-align: left; width: 10%; padding: 5px 0 0 5px;"><img src="assets/images/image.png"></div>
      <h5>Dedicated Server</h5>
      <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available.</p>
      <span><b>From</b></span>
      <div class="price">80$<span>/month</span></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and upvote. 
This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. 
There is no obligation to do this. :)

Comment: had some problem sorry for delay and thanks all the help

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `border-radius` to your `div` that's nested within `ul`: the div that has the `background-color` of `#0169b2`, like so:

```css
ul.pricing-page div{
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
.pricing-page li {
    width: 32%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 22px rgba(157, 184, 209, 0.19);
    background-color: red;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pricing-page">
  <li class="animated bounceInLeft delay-250">
    <div style="background-color: #0169b2">
      <div style="text-align: left; width: 10%; padding: 5px 0 0 5px;"><img src="assets/images/image.png"></div>
      <h5>Dedicated Server</h5>
      <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available.</p>
      <span><b>From</b></span>
      <div class="price">80$<span>/month</span></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </li>
```